# Join tables using django raw query

Tags: python, sql, django

what's wrong with the below query? I want to get the feedback_date from pages_dcb table for all the dials that are in the pages_dataupload table where the registration date of the dials are in the 2022.

```
SELECT pages_dataupload.Dial, pages_dataupload.Registration_Date
FROM pages_dataupload WHERE pages_dataupload.Registration_Date >=  '2022-01-01'
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT pages_bdc.Dial, pages_bdc.feedback_date
) on pages_dataupload.Dial = pages_bdc.Dial;
```

Error

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: near "LEFT": syntax error
At line 1:
SELECT pages_dataupload.Dial, pages_dataupload.Registration_Date
FROM pages_dataupload WHERE pages_dataupload.Registration_Date >=  '2022-01-01'
LEFT
```

and when I add the WHERE clause after join it says no such column called Dial

```
SELECT Dial, Registration_Date FROM pages_dataupload as t1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT Dial, feedback_date FROM pages_bdc as t2
) on t1.Dial = pages_bdc.Dial WHERE t1.Registration_Date >=  '2022-01- 
01';
```

Error

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: ambiguous column name: Dial
At line 1:
SELECT Dial, Registration_Date FROM pages_dataupload as t1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT Dial, feedback_date FROM pages_bdc as t2
) on t1.Dial = pages_bdc.Dial WHERE t1.Registration_Date >=  '2022-01- 
01';
```

Comment: Join should be added before the WHERE clause, also please share your code

Comment: Please *don't* make raw queries...

Comment: It's on local server and i'm using it due to the performance as the database is huge